# Chart.js timeseries x ticks overlapping due to weekend

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I use Chart.js to plot a line chart. My x axis is a **timeseries**.
However, I have ticks overlapping due to weekend data.

Is there any way to avoid overlapping ticks? I used "autoskip: true" but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's how my configs look like:

```
           x: {
              parsing: false,
              type: "timeseries",
              time: {
                displayFormats: {
                  second: "HH:mm",
                  minute: "HH:mm",
                  hour: "HH:mm",
                  day: "MMM d",
                },
                tooltipFormat: "d MMM HH:mm",
              },
              grid: {
                display: false,
              },
              ticks: {
                autoskip: true,
              },
            },
```

And this is how the overlapping looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you're looking for by writing a callback function that checks if the `value` is a weekend day

```
new Date(Date.parse(value)).getDay() == 1 || new Date(Date.parse(value)).getDay() == 2
```

If it is we just don't return it. Otherwise we return the value without changes. 
This is how your config should look like:

```
x:{
   type: 'timeseries'
   time:{
         unit:'day',
   },
   ticks:{
        callback: function(value){
            //if weekend dont return the tick label
            if(new Date(Date.parse(value)).getDay() == 1 || new Date(Date.parse(value)).getDay() == 2 )
                return
            return value
        }
   }
}
```